# Yii module actions url

Tags: module, yii, action

I have in my main project views/layouts/main.php the following 'events' module actions

```
array('label'=>'Events', 'url'=>'#', 'visible'=>UserUtility::isUser(), 'items'=>array(
                array('label'=>'Konzerte', 'items'=>array(
                    array('label'=>'Erstellen', 'url'=>array('events/booking/create')),
                    array('label'=>'Verwalten', 'url'=>array('events/booking/admin')),
                )),
```

If I click on 'Erstellen' the module action works perfectly. If I click on Verwalten afterwards I get the error

```
Error 404 Unable to resolve the request "events/events/concert/admin".*
```

The controller action obviously adds another

```
events/
```

in front of it if I'm already on a page from my events module. How can I overcome this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to create this url with [createAbsoluteUrl()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#createAbsoluteUrl-detail) or add slash before /events

```
array('label'=>'Verwalten', 'url'=>array('/events/booking/admin')),
```

Comment: adding a slash in front of it worked for me! Thanks a lot I really didn't know this can cause such problems.

Comment: If you are in the `events` module in `booking` controller you could also just use: `'url'=>array('admin'))`,